# Visually move from one html element to another - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-lists

For context sake this a school work where I type text into input field and I get options from database that suggest items which have same letters as user has written. It has simple name database attached.

I receive AJAX response and make that into array of names.
I have ul element underneath search field and names which come from response I populate as li items in this ul list. This all works.
What I need is functionality when pressing up / down arrow keys to move from input field into those list items.

on my first try I chose to make datalist instead of ul and I populated datalist with option elements, this worked well as I could move from input to datalist options. However, further down the road I needed to attach event listeners to options which is not possible. Hence I then went to ul / li version.
I cant seem to be able to work out how can I switch from input element into li items.

what i have tryed:

I have eventlistener keydown on input field to check if DownArrow is pressed. This works. Then i tryed following (names is the id of ul).

```
let list = document.getElementById('names');
list.firstChild.focus();
list.firstChild.select();
```

Here I get error that "list.firstChild.select is not a function" and im stuck.

[link to current version](https://student.labranet.jamk.fi/~N2942/harj4/t3/h4t3.html)

Comment: Could you provide more code / codepen Preview ?

Comment: How does your html look, expecially the list?

Comment: @SankalpBhamare added link to current version, at the end of original post

Comment: @Gh05d added link to current version in original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for element.focus() to work on list item (which it does not by default) you have to add tabindex property to list item.

for example:

*listitem*.setAttribute('tabindex',1);

Answer (score 0):

Judging your code, the reason you get the error `list.firstChild.select is not a function` is because you try to use the `focus()` method on an element which does not have it. Basically, you can use it on an `<input />` element, but it won't work on a `<li>` item.

According to [DOM level 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html), only the following Elements have a `focus` method:

- HTMLInputElement
- HTMLSelectElement
- HTMLTextAreaElement
- HTMLAnchorElement
- HTMLAreaElement

Comment: Thank you. I also found now that I can add tabindex property to list item which makes it possible to use focus! Im able to switch to list now.